# NodeJS: How to get the same hour from Postgresql

Tags: node.js, postgresql, datetime

I'm using a Postgresql database where the field departure_date is TIMESTAMP without timezone and the hour saved is:

[image]

However, after make a query to database in Node I'v got this hour:

[image]

As you can see, it's not the same hour that there is in database.

I'm accesing to database with a pool:

```
import {Pool} from "pg";
import config from "../../config";

const pool = new Pool({
    user: config.db_youmalou.user,
    password: config.db_youmalou.password,
    database: config.db_youmalou.name,
    host: config.db_youmalou.host,
    max: config.db_youmalou.pools,
    port: config.db_youmalou.port
});

module.exports.pool = pool;
```

Ho can I get the same hour after making the query?